# Texture of Raw or Roasted Chickpea

Tags: raw, chickpeas

I read some article if raw chickpeas are not safe. I was given chickpeas by someone. He didn't know if the chickpeas were raw or roasted. The chickpeas I got have a crunchy texture and when I press them with two fingers, they easily turn into a floury. Is it roasted chickpea and safe to eat without cooking?

Answer (score 3):

Dry chickpeas which you can easily crush between your fingers may or may not have been roasted, but have definitely been cooked.

Comment: It's a while since I've tried this, so can't remember if "easily", but after an overnight soak alone chickpeas can be crushed by hand.

Comment: @ChrisH They can be broken up a bit, but not easily. And the OP was talking about dry chickpeas... soaked chickpeas which were re-dried would have roughly their original texture.

Comment: Yes, what I'm not sure is what they'd do if soaked, then surface dried, then crushed.  I reckon you're probably right based on the last time I made falafel - which I should do again soon

Comment: ... Also I should try roasting them

Comment: IME roasted falafels suck. The surface dries out rather than browning properly.

Comment: The recipe I used was soak, break up with a food processor, form, then fry. I flattened them so I could shallow fry them.  I did try them in the oven and agree they ended up rather dry.  I wasn't clear  having failed to edit my previous comment in time but I meant roasted chickpeas as a snack